# Why do we solve non-linearity in hyperbolic PDEs that way?

Tags: nonlinear-equations, hyperbolic-pde

I am used to solve parabolic or elliptic non-linear PDE and the common methods to tackle non-linearity are Picard's iteration and Newton's method. I am a bit confused by the way things are done with hyperbolic equations.

For example, with the classical inviscid Burgers' equation in the non-conservative form:

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0
\end{align}
$

I've seen that it can be solved simply by an upwind scheme if we use the conservative flux form without adding anything concerning the non-linearity:

$\begin{align}
F(u) = \frac{u^2}{2} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F(u)}{\partial x} = 0
\end{align}
$

Why is it so? Is it because we commonly use explicit method for hyperbolic methods? Or is it due to some properties from the conservative form? Would we still need a Jacobian if we use an implicit scheme with the Newton's method for example?

Thanks.

Comment: *Is it because we commonly use explicit method for hyperbolic methods?* Yes, and there are good reasons for that.  *Would we still need a Jacobian if we use an implicit scheme with the Newton's method for example?* Yes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The good thing about the conservative form is that this comprises multiple models, such as [Shallow Water Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations#Conservative_form), [Euler Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)#Conservation_form) or [traffic models](http://www.clawpack.org/riemann_book/html/Traffic_flow.html).

An essential feature of hyperbolic equations is the fact that even continuous initial data $u_0(x)$ can lead to discontinuous solutions, a famous example is [(inviscid) Burgers equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation#Inviscid_Burgers%27_equation) with sinusoidal initial data.
This lack of meaningfulness of point data led to the development of [Finite Volume Methods](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02100732v2/document), which formulate your scheme in terms of cell/volume averages instead of point values:

$$u_i(t)  := \frac{1}{\Delta x} \int_{x_{i-1/2}}^{x_{i+1/2}} u(x,t) \mathrm d x.$$

Integration of the conservation law in conservative form $u_t + F(u)_x = 0$ over the $i$'th cell gives

\begin{align}
\int_{x_{i-1/2}}^{x_{i+1/2}} u_t + F(u)_x \mathrm d x = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \Delta x \cdot u_i(t) + F(u) \Big \vert^{x_{i+1/2}}_{x_{i-1/2}} = 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} u_i(t) + \frac{1}{\Delta x} \Bigg( F\bigg(u \Big(x_{i +1/2}^L, t \Big) \bigg) - F\bigg(u \Big(x_{i -1/2}^R, t \Big) \bigg)\Bigg) = 0,\end{align}
irrespective of your particular flux function $F(u)$!
Above, $u\Big(x_{i +1/2}^L,t \Big)$ denotes the value on the left of the cell interface $i \rightarrow i+1$ and $u\Big(x_{i -1/2}^R,t\Big)$ the value on the right of the $i -1 \rightarrow i$ interface. These values have to be somehow determined based on the (only available) cell averages $u_i(t)$. The simplest way would be taking simply the cell average $u_i(t)$, more sophisticated methods use also the neighboring values to construct polynomial interpolations (leading first to degree-one polynomials with limiters and more general to [WENO](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/070679065), [ENO](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA261844.pdf)).

Then the choice of your time integration scheme determines whether you have an explicit scheme or an implicit one, where for general $F(u)$ you would also have to run Newton-Raphson iterations. For FVM, Runge-Kutta methods with a particular property are desired. For an introduction, you can take a look at [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-221/S0025-5718-98-00913-2/S0025-5718-98-00913-2.pdf), [this](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA376446.pdf), [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.04621.pdf) or [this](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/sg/implicitSSP.pdf) paper.

It should be said that in many Finite Volume programs you do not use the flux $F$ coming from your model, but instead a particular approximation (termed *numerical flux*), leading to the famous Lax-Friedrichs, Rusanov or Engquist-Osher schemes. For the Euler equations in particular, the [HLLC](https://edanya.uma.es/NSPDE/cursos/toro/2-HLL+HLLC.pdf) scheme is the classical approach.

Comment: Thanks for the detailled answer! I've heard/read a bit of everything you wrote about before but it is better to have something summarize like this for me with nice references. In the mean time, I understood where my confusion about non-linearity was coming from: I'm used to use implicit schemes, so I didn't understand that with an explicit scheme, you don't need to care about the non-linearity because there is only 1 unknown which is coming from the forward Euler in time for exemple. So my problem was coming from my shallow knowledge of explicit method!

Comment: Happy to help! In case you want to learn more about numerical schemes for conservation laws, I recommend this [lecture notes](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/math/nhdgl/numcl_notes_HOMEPAGE.pdf). I also added some more references.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Always tough to know the must-read on a new topic!